# If $\{x\} + \{1/x\} = 1$ then evaluate $\{x^3\} + \{1/x^3\}$ where $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of$x$

Tags: functions

I cannot seem to find any $x$ which satisfies the given equation.
Let $\{x\}$ be $f$ where $f$ belongs to $[0,1)$

$$f + 1/f = 1$$

$$\frac{f^2 - f + 1}{f} = 0$$

Now as $f$ cannot be $0$, $x$ cannot be an intenger
Also there are no real roots of $f^2 - f + 1 = 0$ as $D<0$.

Comment: $\{1 / x\} \neq 1 / \{x\}$

Comment: There are plenty of such $x$.  One is about $10.9083269$ since $0.9083269+ \frac{1}{10.9083269} \approx 1$.

Answer (score 6):

You argue correctly that $\{x\} + 1/\{x\}$ has no solutions, which follows from the well-known inequality that $z + 1/z \ge 2$ for all real $z$. But, as the comments point out, that isn't the equation you were given. Here are some generous hints:

1. $\{x\} + \{1/x\} = 1$ is equivalent to saying that $x+1/x = n$ is an integer.
2. Then $n^3$ (also an integer) equals $x^3 + 1/x^3 + 3n$.

Can you finish from here?